# Android firebase get event equal to index

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How To get all event and check `index =-L61MIZORBalbOLJBBSk` 
Then get value("owned"):

[image]

I have try this one but not working

```
string eventkey =-L61MIZORBalbOLJBBSk 


final String eventkey = ds.child("key").getValue(String.class);

Query query1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                               .child("users")
                               .orderByChild("userid")
                               .equalTo(userid);
                         query1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
        Log.e("eventvalue", "" + ds.child("events").getValue());

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("userserror", "" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If you need a list, then probably the best aproach is to use Firebase-ui-database the library include a FirebaseRecycler for indexed data
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So the code in your `onDataChange` will need to handle those multiple children by looping over `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
    for (DataSnapshot child: ds.getChildren()) {
        Log.e("eventvalue", "" + child.child("events").getValue());
    }
}
```

#### Alternate data structure

But also consider if your data structure is the best for your use-case right now. You have a list of `users`, and each user already has a unique identified called `userid`. Instead of storing each user under a push ID, I'd recommend storing each user under their `userid`.

In code you probably now store the users with something like:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatbase.getInstance().getReference("users");
ref.push().setValue(user);
```

To get the structure I recommend, instead store them with:

```
ref.child(user.getUserid()).setValue(user);
```

Now each user is stored directly under their `userid`. That means that if you know a `userid`, you can look the user up without needing a query. Your code becomes:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                               .child("users")
                               .child(userid);
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
        Log.e("eventvalue", "" + ds.child("events").getValue());

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("userserror", "" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Node the lack of a loop in `onDataChange` and (more importantly) the lack of `orderByChild().equalTo()` in the query. This is just a direct look up, which:

1. Is easier to code.
2. Automatically means that each user can be stored only once, since the keys are automatically unique.
3. Scales much better, since you don't need a query.

Comment: Thnak you for 
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                               .child("users")
                               .child(userid);

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code:

```
ds.child("events").getValue()
```

Returns a `Map`. So all you need to do is to iterate over the map. Please see the following code:

```
Query query1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                   .child("users")
                   .orderByChild("userid")
                   .equalTo(userid);
             query1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot ds) {
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) ds.child("events").getValue();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getKey().equals(eventkey() {
                Log.e("TAG", entry.getKey());
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("userserror", "" + databaseError);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank  you Alex Mamo